# Create database from existing table in sqlite

Tags: database, sqlite

I have a table. For example:
    CREATE TABLE temp AS SELECT * FROM range(20)

How i can create in sqlite a new database with one command with the table temp?

Comment: What RDMS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Since your in sqlite, in the command line just type:

```
 sqlite3 datbase_name.db
```

This will create a new database called database_name.db, now to create your table to this database just type:

```
 sqlite3 database_name.db "CREATE TABLE .......;"
```

Type your create table statement inside the quotes.

For more info, please take a look at their [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html).

Answer (score -1):

I think that would depend on the DBMS but this may be what you're looking for.

**COPY Command Syntax**

"COPY {FROM database | TO database | FROM database TO database} {APPEND|CREATE|INSERT|REPLACE} destination_table [(column, column, column, ...)] USING query"

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/apb.htm